# What is the point of testing Axios with JEST

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

So I've been reading on how to test axios in react using JEST. For instance, this article by Robin Wieruch https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest/. The thing I don't understand is that in these examples, we actually have dummy data that we expect the API to return. However, I could change that dummy data to be anything really, and the test would still pass. So what is the point?

Update: Adding code from the article.

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { fetchData } from './';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('fetchData', () => {
  it('fetches successfully data from an API', async () => {
    const data = {
      data: {
        hits: [
          {
            objectID: '1',
            title: 'a',
          },
          {
            objectID: '2',
            title: 'b',
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
    await expect(fetchData('react')).resolves.toEqual(data);
  });

  it('fetches erroneously data from an API', async () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Network Error';

    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage)),
    );

    await expect(fetchData('react')).rejects.toThrow(errorMessage);

  });
});
```

Comment: If you can change the dummy data to be anything, then you're not testing the right thing. If you are trying to make a point about the article's content, and the license is compatible with CC-by-SA, copy the relevant text/code here so we know what you're talking about without having to visit another site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added the code. That is my question; what is my dummy data being tested against?

Comment: _"I could change that dummy data to be anything really, and the test would still pass"_ - yes, because the job of the thing you're testing is to return the data from calling the test double. That suggests the thing you're testing isn't particularly useful - you interact with it using the Axios interface, which you don't own. You also don't test the input side at all - the implementation could be `() => axios.get()`, which wouldn't work in real life, and the tests would still pass.

Comment: That's just a dumb test; that tests that the Jest mocking mechanism works. A real test should be validating that the code which reacts to the axios call reacts correctly to different resulting data/errors/etc.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's not quite _that_ bad, as it doesn't then directly exercise the test double - if the test was `await expect(axios.get()).resolves.toEqual(data)`, that would be purely a test of the test framework. There is implementation, however thin a facade, involved.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right, it does call `fetchData`, my bad. It tests that the code which calls `axios.get` calls `axios.get` successfully, which I suppose has some value. If you squint ;).

Comment: Ok, so if I am following your comments correctly, for this test to be useful, something else has to call this test? E.g. a front-end that is expecting data returned from an API, and instead of doing that, this mock is called returning the data we expect. Yes that has some value!

Comment: No. Your current tests well express the requirement _"`fetchData` should return a promise settling to whatever the call to `axios.get` settles to"_. They're simple tests because that's a simple requirement. But there are requirements of `fetchData` that aren't currently covered, and it's entirely possible that an interface less coupled to Axios would be better overall.